# convert upstart to systemd - run command as root, spawns command off as another user

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, sudo, upstart

I need help with converting an upstart .conf into a systemd .service. Essentially what my .conf file does is this:
`exec su -l foo -c 'cd /var/www/path/to/file ; bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb'`

As far as I can tell, we are running the command as root, and then creating a login shell using our "user":

`root       1  0.0  0.0  5  7 ?        Ss   Date   0:00 su -l foo -c cd /var/www/path/to/file ; bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
foo     2  0.0  0.0  6  8 ?        Ss   Date   0:00 -su -c cd /var/www/path/to/file ; bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

This is what I have so far with my systemd .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=simple boot on start
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=foo
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/path/to/file
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma -C /var/www/path/to/file/config/puma.rb'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I know this is wrong, but it works...sort of. In the sense that I get the process to run, but as root. Not running the command as root to run the process as the "user":

`root      3  0.0  0.0  4  5 ?        Ss   Date   0:00 /usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash -lc bundle exec puma -C /var/www/path/to/file/config/puma.rb`

This is pretty new to me at a new job, so trying to find may around this system. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not meant to just copy things literally into `ExecStart=`, especially those which are just for setup, like changing the working directory or user. Those have different directives (which you already used!) so you should just start your program.

For Puma in particular, you should just start with the [sample systemd unit](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md), and customize it to add the user, working directory, path to puma, and (if applicable) your TLS certificate and key.

Comment: Just for context, I did not just copy what was there over. That has been the result of finding my way to that...solution. The closest I came to getting anything working, using another result was this:

`Type=simple
User=foo
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/path/to/file
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb'
Restart=always`

But the process would kick off, but not persist. I would run once and never restart.

Comment: I did find a solution to my problem, and while it is not ideal, it is a combination of the link Michael sent (which I is why I am marking as resolved). It helped with the `ExecStop=` portion, which I was also having trouble with. But the `ExecStart=` I ended up writing a script to do the things the way I needed to do them.

Comment: Sure, occasionally you do need a script. The point here was that you don't need to use a script to do things that systemd can handle for you, like switching users or changing directories.